# Different properties for different implementation of the Interface

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have interface `Service`

`public interface Service{}`

And multiple implementations

`public class ServiceA implements Service{}`

`public class ServiceB implements Service{}`

Now each service has some kind of configuration, e.g

```
public interface Service{   
   ServiceConfiguration getConfig()
}
```

However each of these implementation requires different configuration. So for example `ServiceA` needs `port`,`version`,`url` , serviceB needs `port`,`socket`,`file` and so on.

What is some elegant and good practice way to achieve this? The only thing that comes to my mind is create implementation of `ServiceConfiguration` (and use it as Marker interface ) for each service, and then cast it, e.g

`public interface ServiceConfiguration {}`

```
public class ServiceAConfiguration implements ServiceConfiguration {
    int port;
    int version;
    String url;
}

public class ServiceBConfiguration implements ServiceConfiguration {
    int port;
    Socket socket;
    File file;
}
```

And then casting it in code like:

```
Service s = new ServiceA(...);
ServiceAConfiguration config = (ServiceAConfiguration)s.getConfig();
```

Is there better way, some kind of best practice or some design pattern for this? So far i have found only `AbstractDocument` design pattern for dealing with properties but i think that is not applicable here.

Thanks for helP!

Comment: I would say that you don't need an interface for the configuration. The concrete implementations of ServiceX will need concrete implementations of the configuration. And I have a strong feeling that the method `Service.getConfig()` is a bad idea. Why would you like to leak the configuration of the service?

Answer (score 3):

You can use genericity in `Service` definition :

```java
public interface Service<T extends ServiceConfiguration>{   
   T getConfig()
}
```

`public class ServiceA implements Service<ServiceAConfiguration>{}`

`public class ServiceB implements Service<ServiceBConfiguration>{}`

```java
public class ServiceAConfiguration implements ServiceConfiguration {
    int port;
    int version;
    String url;
}
```

```java
public class ServiceBConfiguration implements ServiceConfiguration {
    int port;
    Socket socket;
    File file;
}
```

You no longer need to cast the configuration :

```java
Service s = new ServiceA(...);
ServiceAConfiguration config = s.getConfig();
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that you are using `Configuration`s as data carriers, thus the need to expose the actual state (port, url, etc.). I suggest that you change the approach and provide it whatever has to be configured, or create new configured object (whatever is more appropriate for your use case).

Properties make it look like configurations for a connection, so i will use that as placeholder.

```
public interface ServiceConfiguration {

   Connection configureConnection();
}
```

```
public class ServiceAConfiguration implements ServiceConfiguration {
    //properties
    
    @Override
    Connection configureConnection() {
        return a connection using port, version and url;
    }
}
```

```
public class ServiceBConfiguration implements ServiceConfiguration {
    //properties

    @Override
    Connection configureConnection() {
        return a connection using port, socket and file;
    }
}
```

Like this you don't need to expose the actual configuration details to the outside world and consequently you don't need to cast `ServiceConfiguration` to the actual class.

Comment: Do you mean like how [`java.sql.DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) interface has a `getConnection` method to produce a [`java.sql.Connection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html) object? The `DataSource` is merely a holder of data fields needed to connect to database, like username, password, and a bunch of various config parameters that are proprietary to the concrete implementation of `DataSource` specific to a particular database engine (Postgres, MS SQL Server, MySQL, etc.).

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes, exactly like that. Each `ServiceConfiguration` holds a bunch of different properties, and using them returns a configured `Connection`. I believe this is the factory design pattern, or at least a variation of it, but may be wrong.